# Please explain this BASH code (one line)

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, shell

Never seen this used before in BASH:

`pidfile=${PIDFILE-/var/run/service.pid}`

The part I've never seen/used before is the `${PIDFILE-` part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means use `$PIDFILE` if `$PIDFILE` is defined, or `/var/run/service.pid` if `$PIDFILE` is undefined.

Starting with a new shell:

```
$ echo ${PIDFILE-/var/run/service.pid}
/var/run/service.pid
```

Now define PIDFILE:

```
$ PIDFILE=/var/run/myprogram.pid
$ echo ${PIDFILE-/var/run/service.pid}
/var/run/myprogram.pid
```

It is from the old days of Bourne Shell [sh man page](http://mikelward.homedns.org/cgi-bin/manual?system=UNIX&section=0&format=html&type=0&query=sh).

```
   ${parameter-word}
          If parameter is set then substitute its value;
          otherwise substitute word.
```

The other form you might have already seen is `${parameter:-word}`.  It is similar, but behaves differently if `parameter` is set to the empty string.

```
   ${parameter:-word}
          Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null,
          the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise,
          the value of parameter is substituted.
```

To demonstrate:

```
$ set | grep NOSUCHVAR    # produces no output because NOSUCHVAR is not defined
$ echo ${NOSUCHVAR-default}
default
$ echo ${NOSUCHVAR:-default}
default

$ NULLVAR=
$ set | grep NULLVAR      # produces output because NULLVAR is defined
NULLVAR=
$ echo ${NULLVAR-default}

$ echo ${NULLVAR:-default}
default
```

Note how `${NULLVAR-default}` expands to the empty string, because `NULLVAR` **is** defined.

For a full explanation, run "man bash" and search for **Parameter Expansion** by typing "/Parameter Expansion".

The ${parameter-word} bit is hidden away in this explanation:

```
    When  not  performing  substring  expansion, using the forms documented below,
    bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null.  Omitting the colon results
    in a test only for a parameter that is unset.
```

Thanks to Dennis for the correction about set versus null.

Comment: It's not "old way"/"new way". If there's no colon it only checks if the parameter is unset. If there is a colon, it checks whether it's unset or null.

Comment: Missed that part.  Thanks Dennis.  Will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks; the example and solution is very understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Mikel:

shouldn't it be 
    `pidfile=${PIDFILE:-/var/run/service.pid}` the way you are explaining?

Comment: Both are valid.  ${var-default} is the old way from Bourne Shell days.  ${var:-default} is specified by POSIX.  Both work in bash.

Comment: Dennis rightly pointed out that there is a difference is the case of var being set but null.  Updated my answer to reflect that.